# GoogleTest C++ application crashes defining a method

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm developing a GoogleTest application under Visual Studio 2017 using CMake.

The following code compiles and links but if any test is defined then raises an std::bad_alloc exception on the TEST macro.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(WasapiSource_Test, test) {  // <--- Crashes here with std::bad_alloc
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Reoving the test the application runs without error.

Comment: Is this all the code? It seem this is not a [mcve]...

Comment: do you use a precompiled library for gtest? if yes, how was it compiled?

Comment: I downloaded the Google Test libraries and compiled them using Cmake & VS2017.

Today (after sleeping) I created a sample solution on VS2017 and crashed the same way. Then I found out _I was linking libraries and using DLLs from different build types_ (Debug/Release). So then I changed the .lib and .dll files used so tey match and now works on the sample project. I will post this as answer when I check on the production code.